# Want to create triangle shape with box-shadow using css for header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

See below code. That i have tried but not getting box-shadow for that triangle shape.

As seen in above image i want to create a triangle shape with shadow using css.(For responsive view also).

I have also add extra div and try using rotate properties but not getting proper solution.

```css
ul {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: #F16322;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.main-header:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 190px;
  background: #cccccc;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
}

.main-menu {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-menu ul {
  float: left;
}

.main-menu li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.main-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 34px 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main-menu>ul>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-menu>ul>li:last-child>a {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.main-menu li a:hover,
.main-menu li.current-menu-item>a {
  color: #000000;
}

.header-logo {
  float: left;
}

.header-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrap">
      <div class="header-logo">
        <a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="BNPK logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#features_section">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#popular_sign">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact_section">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image]

As seen in above image i want to create a triangle shape with shadow using css.(For responsive view also).

I have also add extra `div` and try using `rotate` properties but not getting proper solution.

Comment: Jignesh, you really need to post a [reprex]  so we can have a look what needs to be done. In the mean time search online for 'css slanted border'. CSS-Tricks [Creating Non-Rectangular Headers](https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/) looks promising...

Comment: mplungjan , See what i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add a box-shadow to an element you are using clip-path on, but i fixed it for you using a workaround ive found once.

```
<head>
<style>
ul {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: #F16322;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.triangle {
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 1px 1px #b0b0aa);
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 190px;
}

.triangle::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:  #cccccc;
  color:  #cccccc;
  --p: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: var(--p);
  clip-path: var(--p);
  content: '';
}

.main-menu {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-menu ul {
  float: left;
}

.main-menu li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.main-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 34px 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main-menu>ul>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="triangle">
  </div>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#features_section">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#popular_sign">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact_section">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Pitzas proposed, a filter would be the solution. Personally, I would prefer to use an SVG for the triangle shape and then apply the shadow to it. Filters are extremely powerful combined with SVGs.

For your shadow, I would use the `feGaussianBlur` filter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur

Here you have an example using it:

http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow.svg